# Python: Help with replacing list comprehension with generators

Tags: python, code-quality, code-reviews, list, speed

I have written the following code which takes a `coord_list` of points in a 2D coordinate system, a `center` and a `radius` and returns a list of all points from the list having distance at most `radius` from `center`.

```
def points_in_rad(coord_list, center, radius):
    distances = [distance(coord, center) for coord in coord_list]
    result = [coord_list[i] for i in range(len(coord_list)) if distances[i] <= radius]
    return result
```

I am utilising here a function `distance` computing the distance between two points. The code works well but I am expecting `coord_list` to contain many points, say 10k or more. Performing two list comprehensions is thus quite slow and requires some memory and I would like to speed up this function and at the same time reduce the memory requirement. My idea was to use generators. For example, I could just write
`distances = (distance(coord, center) for coord in coord_list)`
but I'm struggling with converting the second list comprehension into a generator also as this requires looking up `distances` at a specific index.

Any ideas on how this can be done or other improvements to the code?

Comment: Tip 1: You could `zip()` two iterables to iterate over them in lockstep. E.g. `[coord for (coord, distance) in zip(coord_list, distances) if distance <= radius]`. Tip 2: You don't have to create a list or generator over the distances: `[coord for coord in coord_list if distance(coord, center) <= radius]`

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering Stack Exchange doesn't do coding help...](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: @amon thanks, these are helpful tips!

Comment: @gnat I wasn't aware that this is the wrong place to ask. Is there a SE site to ask coding question?

Comment: see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't need `distances` at all. You could simply do:

```
def points_in_rad(coord_list, center, radius):
    return (coord for coord in coord_list if distance(coord, center) <= radius)
```

... although I think it would be more readable like this:

```
def points_in_rad(coord_list, center, radius):
    for coord in coord_list:
        if distance(coord, center) <= radius:
            yield coord
```

In general, if you ever find yourself doing `for i in range(len(something))` in Python, you're missing something.

Also, the function name is ambiguous. At first I thought it meant `points_in_radians`, because that's what "rad" usually stands for in my experience. I don't think it's a good idea to save 3 characters that way.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, providing. very "pythonic" solution. Don't understand why you got a downvote, really like this solution!